# how to untar specific files recursively in linux?

Tags: linux, tar, recursive

I have lots of tar(**.tar.bz2**) files containing multiple file types in a **recursive directory**.
I want to extract just one type of file(let's say **.txt** files) from all the directories. How do i do that?
I have this command to **extract all the files** in each directory:

```
for file in *.tar.bz2; do tar -jxf "${file}"; done
```

I want to extract only the **".txt"** files instead of all.

Comment: I believe my question is different from the question in the link. I have to extract the specific files recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the GNU tar manpage:

> Thus, to extract files whose names end in `.c', you can use:
>
> ```
> $ tar -xf foo.tar -v --wildcards '*.c'
> ```

So for you case, I'd go with:

```
for file in *.tar.bz2; do tar -jxf "${file}" --wildcards '*.txt'; done
```

Answer (score 1):

With bsdtar, you can specify a glob:

```
for file in *.tar.bz2; do tar -jxf "$file" '*.txt'; done
```

With gnutar, you need to add the flag --wildcards:

```
for file in *.tar.bz2; do tar -jxf "$file" --wildcards '*.txt'; done
```